# Modify JSON after getting a response from sequelize

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, json, sequelize.js

I get a `JSON` from my sequelize function. This i have to modify, because i have to send it to a database importer, who needs it in a fixed form. 
Is there a way to customize this function so that I get back the desired result ?

models:

```
User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.SurveyResult)
  }`

    SurveyResult.associate = function (models) {
    SurveyResult.belongsTo(models.User)
```

The function:

```
  async mediImport (req, res) {
    try {
      const transaction = await User.findAll({

        where: { released: true },
        // Select forename as Vorname, name as Nachname
        attributes: [
          ['forename', 'PAPPS286'],
          ['name', 'Nachname'],
          ['birthdate', 'PADPS60']
        ],

        include: [{ model: SurveyResult, attributes: ['result'] }]

      }).map(user => user.toJSON())

      res.send({
        transaction

      }
      )
    }
```

this is the `JSON` which i get from the function:

```
{
    "transaction": [
        {
            "PAPPS286": "Tes",
            "Nachname": "Josef",
            "PADPS60": null,
            "SurveyResults": [ {
                    "result": {
                        "name": "blau",
                        "email": "mail",
                        "birthdate": "01.02.1990"
                    }
                }]
        },
        {
            "PAPPS286": "Dampf",
            "Nachname": "Hans",
            "PADPS60": null,
            "SurveyResults": [
                {
                    "result": {
                        "name": "blau",
                        "email": "mail",
                        "birthdate": "01.02.1990"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },    
      ]
    },
```

This is the `JSON` form i need:

```
{
        "transaction": [
            PAD{
                "PAPPS286": "Tes",
                "Nachname": "Josef",
                "PADPS60": null,
                "MH":  {
                            "name": "blau",
                            "email": "mail",
                            "birthdate": "01.02.1990"

            },
            PAD{
                "PAPPS286": "Dampf",
                "Nachname": "Hans",
                "PADPS60": null,
                "MH":  {
                            "name": "blau",
                            "email": "mail",
                            "birthdate": "01.02.1990"
                        }

            },    
          ]
        },
```

Perhaps there is a way to modify the `JSON` after i get it back. But i dont Knoe how this can be work.

Comment: maybe loop through each data in the json result from the function and format it in a new json object then add it to a json array

Comment: you can just take the output of this function (that's a simple JSON) and modify it as u need. You could use the map function, you are already doing it to get the JSON values of results

Comment: The second code bit of JSON that you need is not valid JSON. What is `PAD` and where does that come from? Is that supposed to be a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below `map` does what I think you are looking for. You may need to modify it, especially around accessing the variables you need, based on the key. (`t.PAPPS286` and `t.PADPS60`)

Additionally, I am only grabbing the first survey result `SurveyResults`. Unsure what you want if there are none or if there are more than 1.

```js
var obj = {
  "transaction": [{
      "PAPPS286": "Tes",
      "Nachname": "Josef",
      "PADPS60": null,
      "SurveyResults": [{
        "result": {
          "name": "blau",
          "email": "mail",
          "birthdate": "01.02.1990"
        }
      }]
    },
    {
      "PAPPS286": "Dampf",
      "Nachname": "Hans",
      "PADPS60": null,
      "SurveyResults": [{
        "result": {
          "name": "blau",
          "email": "mail",
          "birthdate": "01.02.1990"
        }
      }]
    },
  ]
}


obj.transaction = obj.transaction.map((t) => {
  return Object.assign({
    "PAPPS286": t.PAPPS286,
    "Nachname": t.Nachname,
    "PADPS60": t.PADPS60,
    "MH": {
      "name": t.SurveyResults[0].result.name,
      "email": t.SurveyResults[0].result.email,
      "birthdate": t.SurveyResults[0].result.birthdate
    }
  })
})

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const login = async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    const body = req.body;
    const getLogin = await db.tbl_login.findOne({
      attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt"] },
      where: {
        email: body.email,
      },
      raw: true,
      nest: true,
      include: [
        {
          model: db.tbl_role,
          as: "role",
          attributes: ["role_types", "is_active"],
        },
        {
          model: db.tbl_centre,
          as: "centre_info",
          attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt"] },
        },
      ],     
    });
    const isValidPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
      body.password,
      getLogin.password
    );
    let SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
   
    if (isValidPassword) {
      let token = jwt.sign(
        { id: getLogin.id, name: getLogin.name, email: getLogin.email },
        SECRET_KEY,
        {
          expiresIn: 5000,
        }
      );
      const modify={...getLogin} --> Modify response and remove password value
      modify.password='*******************'       
      const data = {
        modify,
        token: token,
      };

      return userResponse(res, 200, data, "welcome to dashboard", "");
    }
    return userResponse(res, 401, "", "", "invalid email and password");
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log("errorrr", error);
    return userResponse(res, 500, "", "", error.message);
  }`enter code here`
.............Response ------------ Result
[![`enter image description here`][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fulRe.png
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34737764)